# Given a random variable whose density is given by a uniform distribution, can we use the expected value to calculate another expected value?

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution, density-function

If given a random variable X whose density is given by the following uniform distribution,

$$p(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1  & \ 0 <x < 40 \\
       \\
      0 & \text{else}
   \end{cases}$$

the price of x is x^2. Say we wanted to find the expected cost would we integrate like this

$\int_{0}^{40} x^2 * p(x) \,dx$

and take our final answer as the result of this or like this?

$\int_{0}^{40} x * p(x) \,dx$

and then we would square the latter to get the cost?

They seem very similar yet they yield different results. Can anyone explain what the procedure is here and why?

Comment: Your $p(x)$ does not integrate to $1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy p(x) would integrate to what then? why can't we just say since we're on the interval where it is equal to 1 that its a constant?

Comment: Review the definition of a probability density function.